# Using simplex method to show that a linear program has no finite optimal solution

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

Suppose I was given a linear program like

$$\max z = - x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 $$

s.t. $$ 3x_1 + x_2 - 4x_3 \leq  4$$
       $$x_1 - x_2 - x_3 \leq 10$$
       $$x_1 - 2x_2 + 6x_3 \leq 9 $$
       $$x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0 \ .$$

It's easy to verify geometrically that this problem is unbounded, but how can I use the *simplex method* to show that this problem has no finite optimal solution? I am also confused about what it really means to be a *finite* solution, because the unreadable, chaotic, confusing and contradictable literature of linear programming cannot give me another better definition than "$z$ can be as big as possible". I am not so much concerned about this particular example above more than understand how the simplex method could be used in this case.

Comment: There is a brief description of the Simplex method [here](http://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklth/personal/ghulchak/optimization/2014/simplex14.pdf). In particular, the second page contains a diagram that you can find useful. Note that it is for minimization, so you need to do the adjustment to fit your setup (i.e. maximization).

Answer (score 0):

When an LP is unbounded, the (primal) simplex method will terminate with a basic feasible solution (call it $x^{*}$ and a ray (call it $r$) such that along the path $x^{*}+\alpha r$, $\alpha > 0$, the points are all feasbile and the objective function is monotonically increasing (or decreasing if your problem is a minimization.)